# Linked server returned message "Query timeout expired."

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, etl, query-timeout

We have two separate SQL Servers. On one server we have a data warehouse (DWH), on the other we have sales information database.

Now on the DWH server there is an ETL job that collects the information from the sales server. The job runs daily after midnight. The DWH collects the information via linked server from the sales database.

Now, the most time the ETL job runs without any problems. But sometimes it fails because of query timeout. We have found out, that there is a specific pattern: The failure happens every 11th day. So on the 11th day the ETL job fails to collect information.

The following error occurs:

> SQLNCLI11 for linked server “my linked server” returned message “Query timeout expired.”

Note: The job fails usually 10 minutes after start.

We have searched everything and could not found out what this issue causes. Also we know that the amount of data is every time, almost the same. Also there is no any scheduled job that runs all 11 days or something.

The remote query timeout on the linked server is set to 0.

Our next step will be, to turn off the antivirus programm on the sales server, to check if this causes the problem.

Does anyone have any clue or idea, where i can search further to find the problem?

Comment: A microsoft supporter has already checked the server logs and he didnt find anything special. We will check the logs on the next 11th day again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question with regards to why the query is slow on the 11th day, but hopefully it helps clarify why it fails after 10 minutes.

You mention:

> The remote timeout on the linked server is set to 0.

Intuitively, this might seem like there is no limit.

What it actually does is use the `sp_configure` default for [remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017), which is 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Setting the query timeout *on the linked server* to a higher value, perhaps 1200 seconds (20 minutes), will likely allow your job to complete.  And hopefully job completion will provide some insight into why it's taking so much longer on this specific day.

I think the setting is a little confusing, as discussed another question here on the site: [Linked server connections to Multi-subnet failover cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207389/linked-server-connections-to-multi-subnet-failover-cluster)

Answer (score 2):

The old SQL Server [RAISERROR-hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql/46146880#46146880) does the trick for me.

```
RAISERROR(N'', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

If you can call it in your remote code more often than those default 600 seconds (10 minutes) then you can use it.

It just forces buffer flushing and this is enough to overcome your **[remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option)** limitation.

**In details.** I have a stored procedure on a SQL Server instance. That instance is linked.
This procedure calls (especially in loops)

```
  PRINT CONCAT('Buffer spamming to prevent "Query timeout expired"; at ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),114))
  RAISERROR(N'', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Then I invoke this procedure through the Linked Server feature on another SQL Server instance.

```
EXECUTE   MyNamedLinkedServer.MyDb.MyScheme.MyRemoteStoredProcedure
```

**Warning!** It is not tested in SQL Server 2019.

**Basically** we have two weird options in this situation.
First is to remember to configure [remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option)

```
EXECUTE   sp_configure 'remote query timeout', <your_value_seconds>;
```

for every new DB instance.
Other is to remember to use the [RAISERROR hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql/46146880#46146880).
Data volumes are changing, right people may change their job. Sooner or later you'll get into this trouble in any way.

**Sadly to say** but we can't set the `remote query timeout` on connection or session levels. IMHO

In current circumstances and for a robustness I would implement some queue analogue in SQL Server. I mean that I request some work and put parameters through the Linked Server feature. Later I check for results, periodically.

**On the other weird hand**, I have procedures that do not use [RAISERROR hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306945/how-do-i-flush-the-print-buffer-in-tsql/46146880#46146880), at all. But they always work stable for hours.
I did my best trying to realise what is going on there.
I can say that they have almost no `SET NOCOUNT ON` and their loops do not hung for a long time and sub-procedures' calls are no longer than 10 minutes.